# Tranforming a Map containing Sets into a Map of Set-Sizes

Tags: java, hashmap, set, java-stream

This is my hash map:

```
HashMap<Customer, HashSet<Car>> carsBoughtByCustomers = ...
```

How can I get a new `HashMap` that will contain for each *customer* the amount of *cars*, i.e. the size of the `HashSet`?

I want to do this *without loops*, but *using streams* only.

*My attempt:*

```
HashMap<Customer, Integer> result = (HashMap<Customer, Integer>)
    carsBoughtByCustomers.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a [*terminal operation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) in order to obtain a result from the stream, [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) in this case, which expects a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)).

`map()` - is an *intermediate operation*, it produces another stream, i.e. it's meant to transform the stream-pipeline but not to generate a result. Therefore, a stream-statement like this `myMap.entrySet().stream().map()` results to a `Stream`, and is **not** assignable to a variable of type `Map`.

```
Map<Customer,Integer> result = carsBoughtByCustomers.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().size()
            ));
```

*Sidenotes:*

- Writing code against interfaces like `Map` and `Set`, not concrete types like `HashMap` and `HashSet`, makes your code more flexible. See: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)
- A stream without a terminal operation is perfectly valid, i.e. it would compile (*if there are no errors is the code*), but would not be executed.